# Get name of the current Snowpark Python Stored Procedure

Tags: python, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

is it possible to retrieve the name of the currently running python sproc?

For example if I have a python proc

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copydata(fromtable VARCHAR, totable VARCHAR, count INT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'run'
AS
$$
def run(session, from_table, to_table, count):

 session.table(from_table).limit(count).write.save_as_table(to_table)

 return "SUCCESS"
$$;
```

I would like to return "SUCCESS " + PROC_NAME

Comment: What *should* work is `__file__` per Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-43. However, this is returning `_udf_code.py` (presumably because this is the template python script that Snowflake uses when compiling a procedure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found two different ways:

```sql
create or replace procedure
    some_sproc()
returns
    string
language
    python
runtime_version = 3.8
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler = 'some_sproc'
as $$
import inspect
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

def some_sproc(session: Session) -> str:
    return inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
$$;
```

```sql
call some_sproc();
```

And the other one:

```sql
create or replace procedure
    some_sproc_h()
returns
    string
language
    python
runtime_version = 3.8
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler = 'handler'
as $$
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
SPROC_NAME = 'some_sproc_h'

def handler(session: Session) -> str:
    return SPROC_NAME
$$;
```

```sql
call some_sproc_h();
```